# Loading of an OSGI bundle into another bundle and use its services

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I want to use one bundle or more into other bundle dynamically by selecting from a UI in java fx . On selecting a bundle name I'm able to install it using

Bundle b = Cntxt.installBundle(file.toURI().toString());

when I run the application and give ss it shows it has been installed but how can I change the state from installed to resolved and then to active hence use  the other bundle???

Answer (score 3):

You need to start it so it becomes active:

```
b.start();
```

That will work unless the bundle has dependencies that cannot be resolved, in which case it will throw an exception and refuse to start.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, I was aware of giving b.start() but there were lots of exception my file was not found on the start ,, may be the path issue ,, now I am able to resolve